# Problems with installing xfce and two task bars

Tags: xfce, xfce-panel

After installing xfce4 I have two task bars as depicted in the following image:

[image]

I wish to have a single black taskbar (the one at the top), and not the white one behind the launcher. 
The white taskbar (at the bottom) is not configured using xfce4-panel. When xfce4-panel is killed- the white slidebars remains.

The Ubuntu version is 18.04.2

I tried to reset the xfce4 options, but it did not worked.
What can be the problem?

Comment: You haven't told us your release of Ubuntu (which will mean the version of XFCE you have installed), however why not just change the panels to be what you like (or remove one or more if unwanted). Settings can be found in ~/.config/xfce4/ though I'd use the gui to make changes myself.

Comment: What's your problem? please provide more details.

Comment: Ubuntu version is 18.04.2.
The problem is that I want to have a single taskbar(the black one in the top).

Comment: @guiverc I think the white taskbar is not configured using xfce4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that gnome was not completely uninstalled.

Simply did `sudo apt-get purge gnome-panel` and the problem was solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete an Xfce Panel by first right-clicking over it and choosing the Panel Preferences option:

From here, click on the Xfce Delete Panel Icon icon to delete the panel.
This [link](http://www.linuceum.com/Distros/osDesktopConfigXfce.php) provides more details.

Comment: Not working...
If the Xfce Panel is killed, then the white taskbars are remain. 
I want to delete the white taskbars, not the one triggered by Xfce panels

Comment: @user3563894 Do you mean you have two white panels left, one at the top and one at the bottom when you killed the xfce-panel (`xfce4-panel -q`)?

Comment: @mook765 yes. exactly